# Generate user interface for manual API testing from code (Postman alternative)

Tags: api, software-testing, web-apis

Postman allows you to define usage examples for your API that you can execute to manually test your endpoints.

I find it cumbersome to use the slow and cluttered GUI to keep these examples in sync with my codebase. I’d rather prefer to *code* these examples and check them in with my version control system. Ideally, some software would be able to parse this code and generate an interface (e.g. a web GUI) that allows me to manually test my endpoints with the examples.

I am aware of Swagger UI but apparently I have to buy into the entire Swagger workflow and generate my APIs from OpenAPI schemas to use it. I wonder if there are alternatives.